# Sorting Numbers Descending Order with C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I want to make a descending number sorter.

I want to ask about what's wrong with my code. Why does my code won't work properly if the 3rd variable `b3` has the lowest value.

Example : `b1 = 90, b2 = 60, b3 = 30` and the result is `90, 30, 30`.

**But** if I inputted another number (as long as the 3rd variable is not the lowest value), my code work perfectly fine.

Example : `b1 = 30 , b2 = 90 , b3 = 60` and the result is `90, 60, 30`

Example : `b1 = 30 , b2 = 60 , b3 = 90` and the result is `90, 60, 30`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int b1,b2,b3,h1,h2,h3;

    cout<<"Masukkan Bilangan 1: ";
    cin>>b1;
    cout<<"Masukkan Bilangan 2: ";
    cin>>b2;
    cout<<"Masukkan Bilangan 3: ";
    cin>>b3;

    if(b1 >= b2 && b1 >= b3){
        h1 = b1;
    }else if(b2 >= b1 && b2 >= b3){
        h1 = b2;
    }else{
        h1 = b3;
    }

    if(b2 >= b1 && b1 >= b3){
        h2 = b1;
    }else if(b2 >= b1 && b2 <= b3 ){
        h2 = b2;
    }
    else{
        h2 = b3;
    }

    if(b1 <= b2 && b1 <= b3){
        h3 = b1;
    }else if(b2 <= b1 && b2 <= b3){
        h3 = b2;
    }
    else{
        h3 = b3;
    }

    cout<<h1<<", ";
    cout<<h2<<", ";
    cout<<h3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not put them into an array and use `std::sort`?

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your program line by line.

Comment: @Dai This is a homework and I'm not allowed to used that. Btw Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @JoseIshak This homework exercise seems of dubious academic utility - sorting numbers this way is not how numbers are optimally sorted.

Comment: learn [Different Sorting Techniques](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/) and [Arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only code that sets `h2` to `b1` is this code:

```
if(b2 >= b1 && b1 >= b3){
    h2 = b1;
```

But `h2` should be set to `b1` if `b1` is between `b2` and `b3`. And that can be true two different ways, and you only test for one of them.

For example, 10 is between 5 and 30. But 10 is also between 30 and 5!

Trying to cover every possible case is not a sensible way to sort more than two numbers. Use a sensible sorting algorithm.

Comment: Hopefully you learn the right lesson though -- you are making things too hard by trying to cover every possible case with separate ad hoc code rather than using a sensible sorting algorithm that uses an organized strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in second nested if condition. If you put the values automatically the value of h2 will become 30. Instead try this..

```
if((b2 >= b1 && b1 >= b3) ||(b3 >= b1 && b1 >= b2)){
        h2 = b1;
    }else if((b2 >= b1 && b2 <= b3 )||(b2 >= b3 && b2 <= b1)){
        h2 = b2;
    }
    else{
        h2 = b3;
    }
```